# Inherit Boostrap Button CSS and override colour explaination

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm hoping someone can explain how I can make a button inherit all of a button's properties from bootstrap but override its colour and explain how it works in layman's terms.

I have a button with the following class:

```
class="btn action-braintree-paypal-logo"
```

Obviously, `btn` has its properties taken from bootstrap (as I am using it) and then I've defined my own `action-braintree-paypal-logo`.

I then have this in my own stylesheet:

```
.action-braintree-paypal-logo {
    background-color:#019cde;
}
```

But the colour keeps defaulting back to bootstraps own colour and I'm failing to understand why.

The stylesheet I'm using is after bootstraps in my head as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can try to override by using `!important`. See also [CSS !important Rule: How to Use It Correctly](https://appendto.com/2016/04/css-important-rule-how-to-use-it-correctly/)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the link tag for the style sheet you are referring to has `rel="stylesheet"` attribute, otherwise the styles are not imported.

Example:

The below CSS will work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

But this one doesn't:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.action-braintree-paypal-logo {
    background-color:#019cde;
}
</style>

<button class = "btn action-braintree-paypal-logo">Test Button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not the issue.

Comment: @James The color is applied to bootstrap button. May be some other style is overwriting the button color in your case.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked developer tools and it's getting its colour from another stylesheet but my custom stylesheet is still later in the head so I'm getting confused.

Comment: You need to overwrite your custom styles using `!important`. You can find the comment above from Lorek Bryanson.

Comment: Although I didn't want to use important tags I've managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline css for this..
class="btn" style="background-color: #019cde; in your button tag

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution CSS specificity:

```
.btn.action-braintree-paypal-logo {
    background-color:#019cde;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
.btn.action-braintree-paypal-logo { background: red; color: #fff; }
```